# processMessage runs twice

Tags: java, openfire, smack

There is a MessageListener listening to processMessage say from user A and when sendMsg is sent form another user to User A , I see processMessage getting invoked twice:

```
public void sendMsg(message){
 Message msg = new Message();
 mess.setBody(message);
 // userid is the userid to whom the message will be sent to and chmanage is an instance of Chat Manager
 Chat chat = chmanage.createChat(<userid>, new CListener());
 chat.sendMessage(msg);
}

class CListener implements MessageListener{

 @Override
 public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {
  ...
  //this gets called twice
 }
}
```

Any reasons for this? Should I use something else like create a PacketCollector or PacketListener?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Listener was used twice for listening to messages and registering it with another user. It worked after creating a separate listener class for that

Comment: facing the same problem. can you please explain bit more?